# Is it recommended to use traits to implement utility functions for structs in external crate?

Tags: rust

I want to implement a simple utility/helper function in Rust. The function just concatenates the path in a struct (from an external crate) and the argument passed. Is it more idiomatic to implement the helper-function as a normal function or as function of a custom trait?

The implementation of the trait-based approach:

```
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

pub trait RepositoryExt {
    fn get_full_path(&self, path_in_repository: &Path) -> PathBuf;
}

impl RepositoryExt for othercrate::Repository {
    // othercrate::Repository's workdir() returns its path
    fn get_full_path(&self, path_in_repository: &Path) -> PathBuf {
        self.workdir().join(path_in_repository)
    }
}
```

With just a function:

```
pub fn get_repository_full_path(repo: othercrate::Repository,
                                path_in_repository: &Path) -> PathBuf {
    repo.workdir().join(path_in_repository)
}
```

The trait-based approach shortens the code when using the helper-function, but I'm worried that it may introduce difficulty to understand where it's defined.

Though both implementations should work, I want to know which is the recommended way in Rust.

Answer (score 3):

(*Disclaimer*: I am not entirely sure about this. If this answer receives enough™ upvotes, I will delete this disclaimer)

---

Good question! I have already seen both solution in the wild and would say that both are valid to use. Or in other words: neither of the two solutions are considered bad.

However, I'd say that **using the `Ext`-trait approach is often a slightly better choice** due to these advantages:

- Many operations feel way more natural to call "on an object" (with dot-notation) than to call a function with both objects.
- Chaining multiple calls looks nice in code because it fits our left-to-right way of reading, whereas with the function-approach the code is harder to read: `f(f(a, f(d, e)), c)`.
- If the user prefers the plain-function style, he can also use it that way with `Trait::func(self_object, arg)`.

But of course there are some disadvantages (you already mentioned one):

- It's harder for the user to understand where the helper-function is defined.
- The user needs to have the trait in scope (read: `use` the trait).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the "disadvantages" cancel each other out (deliberately). You know where the function is defined because presumably you've have to think about which trait to include. My biggest annoyance with the trait is that you have to type it out twice (once for the trait, once for the impl).